# maxima's float() fails to simplify expression

Tags: maxima

Let the sign `=>` mean 'evaluates to'.

On my maxima I get this

```
float(%e^(x + sin(1))) => 2.718^(x + sin(1))
```

altough I would rather expect this

```
float(%e^(x + sin(1))) => 2.718^(x + 0.841)
```

which would be consistent with

```
float(%e^sin(1)) => 2.319
float(x + sin(1)) => x + 0.841
```

which maxima evinces.

Two questions:

1. Why `sin(1)` in exponent is not "floated"?
2. How to achieve this "floatation"?

Answer (score 1):

(1) as to why `sin(1)` doesn't turn into a number -- I think that's a bug.

(2) to get a number, try `ev(foo, numer);` where `foo` is the expression you want. You can write just `foo, numer;` at the input prompt.